# fork() and system() calls not working as I expect

Tags: c, fork, system

I'm playing with the fork() and system() commands and when I run this example code I find that the child process doesn't print the "Song complete..." line after the system call is finished.
Is this normal or have I missed something?

I thought system() would have finished its work then returned to the child process and gone on its merry way to either exit or do additional tasks.  That doesn't happen for this code example.

```
     #include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
     #include <sys/wait.h>  /* waitpid */
     #include <stdio.h>     /* printf, perror */
     #include <stdlib.h>    /* exit */
     #include <unistd.h>    /* _exit, fork */

     int main(void)
     {
       pid_t pid;
       int i;
       pid = fork();

       if (pid == -1) {
          /*
           * When fork() returns -1, an error happened.
           */
          perror("fork failed");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       else if (pid == 0) {
          /*
           * When fork() returns 0, we are in the child process.
           */
          printf("Hello from the child process!\n");
            system("aplay ./SOS_sample.wav");
          printf("Song complete...");
          _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  /* exit() is unreliable here, so _exit must be used */
       }
       else {
          /*
           * When fork() returns a positive number, we are in the parent process
           * and the return value is the PID of the newly created child process.
           */
          int status;
            printf("Waiting on the song to end...\n");
            for (i = 0;i<10;i++){
                    printf("%d\n",i);
                    }
          (void)waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            for (i=0;i<10;i++){
                    printf("%d\n",i);
                    }
       }
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
     }
```

Comment: Isn't it because `printf` is buffering your message and not outputing it immediatly ? Try adding a `\n` at the end of your message to flush its buffer.

Comment: @HalimQarroum is exactly right.  Print to `stderr` or call `fflush(stdout)` after `printf` and you ought to see what you expect.  I believe that whether newline `"\n"` will cause a flush or not is system dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because `printf` buffers your message, and does not immediatly output it on the standard output. In this case, as your child process gets killed right after, your call to `printf` would get totally unnoticed.

Try adding a `\n` at the end of your message to force `printf` to flush his internal buffer :

```
printf("Song complete...\n");
```

Comment: That was it... didn't occur to me that I should flush the buffer.  Thought it would have been flushed as the fork exits.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the problem.

1. You use `printf()` and don't terminate the message with a newline.
2. You use `_exit()` which deliberately avoids flushing buffered output on open file streams (such as standard output).

The basic fix is simple — as accurately diagnosed by [Halim Qarroum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175633/halim-qarroum) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587632/15168):

1. Include the newline in the output message.
2. If you can't include the newline, include `fflush(stdout)` or `flush(0)`.
3. Or use `exit()` instead of `_exit()`.

Each of these will cure the missing message.  As a general rule, if you want a message to appear, end it with a newline.  If you don't, make sure it is produced with `fflush()`, or ensure that `exit()` is used to flush the buffers.